# Is it possible to solve multi objective optimisation problem by PSO technique?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, heuristics

I‘m having two objectives

1. Minimise time
   2.Minimise cost

I want to solve the problem using PSO rather than using MOPSO.
Is it possible to do?

From the internet search , I came to know that by converting the multi objective to single objective . Is it possible.

I would like to know, is that really makes sense.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use decomposition methods, first normalize both costs, then use norm2 of them to convert to one objective optimization. after that you can use PSO or any single objective optimization algorithm.